# Reproducing the behavior of bash's pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of bash pipes using `pipe` and `dup2`, and it works fine for one pipe, because the first and the last have just either input or output redirected, but when I add multiple in a row it doesn't work (when both input and output are redirected to the pipe), the inputs and outputs seem to mess up with each other, so do we need to sleep between each command? I saw while reading documentation that executables are run at the same time and that we shouldn't wait for the previous child process to end so I don't wait. Here's the wrong part of my code:

```c
#include "shell.h"

static int  pfd[2];

void    ms_terminate(int ret) {
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);
    clean_exit(ret);
}

pid_t   execute(const t_shcmd *cmd, char *const *envp, bool in, bool out) {
    pid_t   cpid = 0;

    if (!ft_strcmp(cmd->av[0], "cd")) {
        int fd_in = dup(0), fd_out = dup(1);
        if (in) dup2(pfd[0], 0);
        if (out) dup2(pfd[1], 1);
        close(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[1]);
        builtin_cd(cmd->ac, cmd->av);
        dup2(fd_in, 0);
        dup2(fd_out, 1);
        close(fd_in);
        close(fd_out);
    }
    else if (!(cpid = fork())) {
        if (in) dup2(pfd[0], 0);
        if (out) dup2(pfd[1], 1);
        close(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[1]);
        execve(*cmd->av, cmd->av, envp);
        clean_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (cpid == -1)
        ms_terminate(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return cpid;
}

void    execute_pipeline(const t_shcmd *cmd, char *const *envp) {
    pid_t   cpid;

    if (!(cpid = fork())) {
        execute(cmd, envp, false, true);
        while ((cmd = cmd->pipe)->pipe)
            execute(cmd, envp, true, true);
        execute(cmd, envp, true, false);
        ms_terminate(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    if (cpid == -1) ms_terminate(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
}

void    ms_execute(const t_shcmd *cmd, char *const *envp) {
    pid_t           cpid;

    pipe(pfd);
    while (cmd) {
        if (cmd->pipe)
            execute_pipeline(cmd, envp);
        else {
            cpid = execute(cmd, envp, false, false);
            wait(NULL);
        }
        cmd = cmd->next;
    }
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);
}
```

the struct `t_shcmd` is basically a special chained list declared like this, and obtained by my parser (the problem doesn't come from the parser btw, it comes from the above code):

```c
typedef struct s_shcmd  t_shcmd;

struct s_shcmd {
    t_shcmd     *next, *pipe;
    int         ac;
    char        *av[];
};
```

structured like this:
[image: t_shcmd]

Comment: You only create one pipe

Comment: @ikegami so I need to create two pipes ? or a pipe for each pipe child ?

Comment: Yes; you need a separate pipe for each connection between two processes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of a pipe like a real pipe.

If you want information from `prog1` to go to `prog2`, you will need a pipe.

If you also want information from `prog2` to go to `prog3`, you will need another pipe.

So `prog1 | prog2 | prog3` requires two pipes.

---

Note: Make sure to close all the pipe ends that aren't needed. `prog1` should only have one of the four pipe ends open, `prog2` should only have two, and `prog3` should only have the final one open.

Comment: Okay, that's all the information I needed thanks